# JavaFx Scatter Chart custom Legend

Tags: java, javafx, charts, legend

I have a problem with the legend of my Scatter Chart with JavaFx. I dynamically change the style of the series with the following code:

```
Set<Node> nodes = scatterChart.lookupAll(".series0"); 
                    for (Node n : nodes) {
                        n.setStyle("-fx-blend-mode: multiply ;");
                    }
```

I do this for all series and with different strings inside the setStyle method and it works fine in the Chart. My problem is that these changes do not affect the legend which keeps showing the default colours, shapes etc. of each series and not the ones that I made. Can anyone make any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I posted the question, but I found a solution and I thought I would write it here in case someone else has ever the same problem as I did. I changed the code of the answer as follows :

```
ArrayList<Node> seriesNodes = new ArrayList<Node>();
Set<Node> nodes = scatterChart.lookupAll(.series0); 
                    int flag=0;
                    for (Node n : nodes) {
                        n.setStyle("-fx-blend-mode: multiply ;");
                         if(flag==0){
                             seriesNodes.add(n);
                         }
                         flag++;
                    }
```

I do this for each series, so I save the node of each series in an ArrayList and then after I add all the series to the scatterChart I do the code below:

```
Set<Node> items = scatterChart.lookupAll("Label.chart-legend-item");
             int it=0;
             for (Node item : items) {
                  Label label = (Label) item;
                  label.setGraphic(seriesNodes.get(it));
                  it++;
             }
```

I hope this helps someone as it did for me!